# Converting arraybuffer to blob for downloading as excel file in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, blob, arraybuffer

I am trying to create an excel file that is downloadable from both Firefox and Chrome from an Angular 2+ environment. I have it working perfectly in firefox, but everything i try just doesn't work in Chrome - it downloads the file but when you open it throws an error - "Excel cannot open this file because the file format or file extension is not valid..".

I've tried to set my post responseType as 'arrayBuffer' and then creating a blob then downloading that, with no success. I've tried responseType as:
1)'blob'
2)'blob' as 'json'
3)'blob' as 'blob'

and passing it through to my component that way. Nothing seems to work on Chrome, everything works on Firefox though.

Here are some of my functions i have used to try get Chrome to open this excel.

```
downloadBlob(data: Blob, fileName: string) {
        //output file name
        //detect whether the browser is IE/Edge or another browser
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          //To IE or Edge browser, using msSaveorOpenBlob method to download file.
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, fileName);
        } else {
            //To another browser, create a tag to downlad file.
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
        }
}
```

```
 blobToFile(data: Blob, fileName: string) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style.display = 'none';
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url; a.download = fileName; a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
```

```
downloadArray(data, fileName: string) {
        var blob = new window.Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;   
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.location.href = url;
}
```

I've even tried to use the FileSaver.js plugin to save my blob with the oneliner

`saveAs('blob', 'filename');`

but everything wont read when opening from chrome. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Consider removing `revokeObjectURL()`. This test works and downloads in Chrome: https://batman.dev/static/70844902/

```js
function downloadBuffer(arrayBuffer, fileName) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(
    [ arrayBuffer ],
    { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }
  ))
  a.download = fileName
  a.click()
}
```

Comment: No i tried this approach and no luck. 

I have use the sample code in your example in two ways - first with my service and a data stream returned from the backend - with no luck, same error. And i tried to use a local file to see if it was the data returned that was the issue -  so downloaded my file first through Firefox (with a different function that works in Firefox) saved it to my hard drive, then updated the new function with a path to the local downloaded file - same results, get this error - https://ibb.co/HtkLm2N.
Cant work this out for the life of me 
 - https://ibb.co/4pz2h9j